# semantics of map on a sequence of objects in jq

Tags: json, jq

Suppose I have a file fruit.json containing the following lines:

```
[
  {
    "name": "apple",
    "color": "red",
    "price": 20
  },
  {
    "name": "banana",
    "color": "yellow",
    "price": 15
  },
  {
    "name": "pineapple",
    "color": "orange",
    "price": 53
  }
]
```

If I do `jq '. | map(.)' fruit.json` then I get the original data. That's expected. The second `.` refers to an element in the entire array.

However if I do `jq '.[] | map(.)' fruit.json` then I get this:

```
[
  "apple",
  "red",
  20
]
[
  "banana",
  "yellow",
  15
]
[
  "pineapple",
  "orange",
  53
]
```

Can someone please explain what's going on? Specifically,

1. The `[]` after `.` strips away the brackets from the input array. Do
   we have a name for the `[]` operator? The manual seems to treat it as
   something very basic without definition.
2. Do we have a name for the resulting thing by appending `[]` to `.`?
   Obviously it's not an object. If we do `jq '.[]' fruit.json`
   we can see that it looks very similar to an array.
   But apparently it behaves quite differently.
3. Why is it the case that the `map` function seems to go two
   levels inside instead of one? This is
   more obvious if we do `jq '.[] | map(. | length)' fruit.json`
   and see that the `.` inside the `map`
   function refers to the value part of an (object) element of the input array.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.[]` produces the values of the array or object given to it.

For example,

```
[ "a", "b", "c" ] | .[]
```

is equivalent to

```
[ "a", "b", "c" ] | .[0], .[1], .[2]
```

and produces three strings: `a`, `b` and `c`.

---

```
map( ... )
```

is equivalent to

```
[ .[] | ... ]
```

This means that

```
map( . )    ≡    [ .[] | . ]    ≡    [ .[] ]
```

For an array, that means

```
map( . )    ≡    [ .[0], .[1], ... ]    ≡    .
```

For an object, that means

```
map( . )    ≡    [ .["key1"], .["key2"], ... ]
```

---

> The `[]` after `.` strips away the brackets from the input array.

There are no brackets. `jq` programs don't deal with JSON text, but the data structure it represents.

When given an array or object, `.[]` produces the values of the elements of that array or object.

> Do we have a name for the `[]` operator?

The docs call it the *Array/Object Value Iterator*, but it's really just a specific usage of the indexing operator.

The *Array/Object Value Iterator* is ascribed to `.[]` in the docs, but that's not accurate. It doesn't have to be `.` before it, but an expression must precede it. This distinguishes it from array construction operator.

In technical terms,

- `[]` as a circumfix operator (`[ EXPR ]`) is the array construction operator, and
- `[]` as a postfix operator (`EXPR [ EXPR? ]`) is the indexing operator, and it's specifically called the the array/object value iterator when there's nothing in the brackets.

> Do we have a name for the resulting thing by appending `[]` to `.`? Obviously it's not an object. If we do `jq '.[]' fruit.json` we can see that it looks very similar to an array. But apparently it behaves quite differently.

We call that a stream.

I'm not sure what to call the components of the stream. I usually use "value".

For example,

```
"a", "b", "c"       // Produces a stream of three values.
"abc" / "" | .[]    // Same
```

When serialized to a file with one value per line (as you would get using `-c`), it's called ["JSON lines"](https://jsonlines.org/) with a suggested naming convention of `.jsonl`.

> Why is it the case that the map function seems to go two levels inside instead of one? This is more obvious if we do `jq '.[] | map(. | length)' fruit.json` and see that the . inside the map function refers to the value part of an (object) element of the input array.

No, just one.

In that example,

- The `.[]` iterates over the values of the array.
- The `map` iterates over the values of the objects.